# Accordion content showing empty view When expand the accordion content after "Entry" control focused in page using xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am facing issue in Accordion in xamarin forms. I have entry control outside of the accordion content in the Page. When open accordion content first. Its opening and i can see the view. click on accordion item After click on entry. Its expanding the view but empty view is appearing. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Below are screenshots.

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hkej.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctukf.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDiK2.png

Comment: Can you provide more context? Code, Screenshots

Comment: @Brunco Caceiro please check the screenshots